# Keep param consistent on location change ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using react router v4 to change location in ReactJs.

```js
this.props.history.push("/profile");

<Link to="/profile" />
```

The above code works fine.

Now I want to keep a param consistent in URL `http://localhost:3000?source=test` by using the same code as above.

One approach is that I find all the occurrences in the code and add condition that if params `source=test` exist then append it to the the URL as well but this approach doesn't look fine to me as I have add condition on every `redirect`, `Link` and `history.push`

Second approach that I find is that use of listener on location update given by react router

In my Main Route file

```js
class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
     this.unlisten = this.props.history.listen((location, action) => {
      if (/source=ep/.test(this.props.location.search)) {
        location.search = _startsWith(location.search, "?") ? location.search + "&source=test" : "?source=test"
      }
    });
  }
}
```

With this approach I can easily append the params in search query of react router but the param doesn't show up in URL.

the URL looks like this `http://localhost:3000/profile` and When I get search params from react-router `console.log(this.props.location.search)` it shows the param `source=test` and it's exactly what I want but In this case if user refreshes on this page the search params lost from react-router as well because it's not in the URL.

Can you guys help me to keep `source=test` consistent even in URL.

Comment: This sounds like a bit of an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me. *Why* do you need to keep the query parameter?

Comment: I actually want to keep track of traffic from specific source that's why I need to keep param consistent